# After successfully installing Package [ Laravel ] , the package folder is not found in vendor directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I developed a test package for laravel 5.3, that was working fine. Then uploaded it on GitHub  and Packgist. Now when trying to install using composer, the composer throwing success message like below.

[image]

> But the package folder is not found in the vendor directory.

Sorry for my bad English and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your composer.json contains -

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Sarkerbappa\\Allbdpostcode": "src/Sarkerbappa"
     }
```

But you do not have folder named `Sarkerbappa` in your package. You have put everything under `src` so to get it work chage `src/Sarkerbapp` to `src`.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Sarkerbappa\\Allbdpostcode": "src/"
     }
```

Comment: Changed it, but same result stile now.

Comment: have you update the packagist on packagist.org after make a changes?

Comment: Yes. I have updated in   packagist  .  Also tried  
                              "Sarkerbappa\\Allbdpostcode\\": "src/". But not found any  positive result.

Comment: Try composer dump-autoload.